# facail landmark in my yolo face detection

Tags: python-3.x, yolo

i want to use a face landmark for alignment faces that extracted from my face detection code(using yolov3).

this is my code:

```
import argparse
import sys
import os

from utils import *

#####################################################################
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--model-cfg', type=str, default='./cfg/yolov3- 
face.cfg',
                    help='path to config file')
parser.add_argument('--model-weights', type=str,
                    default='./model-weights/yolov3-wider_16000.weights',
                    help='path to weights of model')
parser.add_argument('--image', type=str, default='',
                    help='path to image file')
parser.add_argument('--video', type=str, default='',
                    help='path to video file')
parser.add_argument('--src', type=int, default=0,
                    help='source of the camera')
parser.add_argument('--output-dir', type=str, default='outputs/',
                    help='path to the output directory')
args = parser.parse_args()

#####################################################################
# print the arguments
print('----- info -----')
print('[i] The config file: ', args.model_cfg)
print('[i] The weights of model file: ', args.model_weights)
print('[i] Path to image file: ', args.image)
print('[i] Path to video file: ', args.video)
print('###########################################################\n')

# check outputs directory
if not os.path.exists(args.output_dir):
    print('==> Creating the {} directory...'.format(args.output_dir))
    os.makedirs(args.output_dir)
else:
    print('==> Skipping create the {} 
directory...'.format(args.output_dir))

# Give the configuration and weight files for the model and load the 
network
# using them.
net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromDarknet(args.model_cfg, args.model_weights)
net.setPreferableBackend(cv2.dnn.DNN_BACKEND_OPENCV)
net.setPreferableTarget(cv2.dnn.DNN_TARGET_CPU)


def _main():
    wind_name = 'face detection using YOLOv3'
    cv2.namedWindow(wind_name, cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)

    output_file = ''

    if args.image:
        if not os.path.isfile(args.image):
            print("[!] ==> Input image file {} doesn't 
exist".format(args.image))
            sys.exit(1)
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(args.image)
        output_file = args.image[:-4].rsplit('/')[-1] + '_yoloface.jpg'
    elif args.video:
        if not os.path.isfile(args.video):
            print("[!] ==> Input video file {} doesn't 
exist".format(args.video))
            sys.exit(1)
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(args.video)
        output_file = args.video[:-4].rsplit('/')[-1] + '_yoloface.avi'
    else:
        # Get data from the camera
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(args.src)

    # Get the video writer initialized to save the output video
    if not args.image:
        video_writer = cv2.VideoWriter(os.path.join(args.output_dir, 
output_file),
                                       cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M', 'J', 
'P', 'G'),
                                       cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS), (

round(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)),

round(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))))

    while True:

        has_frame, frame = cap.read()

        # Stop the program if reached end of video
        if not has_frame:
            print('[i] ==> Done processing!!!')
            print('[i] ==> Output file is stored at', 
os.path.join(args.output_dir, output_file))
            cv2.waitKey(1000)
            break

        # Create a 4D blob from a frame.
        blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(frame, 1 / 255, (IMG_WIDTH, 
IMG_HEIGHT),
                                     [0, 0, 0], 1, crop=False)

        # Sets the input to the network
        net.setInput(blob)

        # Runs the forward pass to get output of the output layers
        outs = net.forward(get_outputs_names(net))

        # Remove the bounding boxes with low confidence
        faces = post_process(frame, outs, CONF_THRESHOLD, NMS_THRESHOLD)
        print('[i] ==> # detected faces: {}'.format(len(faces)))
        print('#' * 60)

        # initialize the set of information we'll displaying on the frame
        info = [
            ('number of faces detected', '{}'.format(len(faces)))
        ]

        for (i, (txt, val)) in enumerate(info):
            text = '{}: {}'.format(txt, val)
            cv2.putText(frame, text, (10, (i * 20) + 20),
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, COLOR_RED, 2)

        # Save the output video to file
        if args.image:
            cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(args.output_dir, output_file), 
  frame.astype(np.uint8))
    else:
        video_writer.write(frame.astype(np.uint8))

    cv2.imshow(wind_name, frame)

    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == 27 or key == ord('q'):
        print('[i] ==> Interrupted by user!')
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

print('==> All done!')
print('***********************************************************')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    _main()
```

my problem is that i want to use a face landmark to alignment faces that extracted by the yoloface detector but i dont know how use a code in my code for facail ladmarking

please help me
thx

Answer (score 0):

You can use dlib and imutils for that. The model can be downloaded here: http://dlib.net/files/

```
import dlib
from imutils import face_utils
import cv2

shape_predictor = dlib.shape_predictor('shape_predictor_5_face_landmarks.dat')
fa = face_utils.facealigner.FaceAligner(self.shape_predictor, desiredLeftEye=(0.2, 0.2))


gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
aligned_face = self.fa.align(frame, gray, dlib.rectangle(left = box[0], top=box[1], right=box[2], bottom=box[3]))
```